# Extract information to work with with pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have this dataframe:

## Column                 Non-Null        Dtype

0   nombre                 74 non-null     object

1   fabricante  -           74 non-null    - object

2   calorias               -74 non-null     -int64
3   proteina               -74 non-null     -int64
4   grasa                  -74 non-null     -int64
5   sodio                  -74 non-null     -int64
6   fibra dietaria         -74 non-null     -float64
7   carbohidratos          -74 non-null     -float64
8   azúcar                 -74 non-null     -int64
9   potasio                -74 non-null     -int64
10  vitaminas y minerales  -74 non-null     -int64

I am trying to extract information like this:

```
cereal_df.loc[cereal_df['fabricante'] == 'Kelloggs', 'sodio']
```

The output is (good, that is what I want to extract in this case right?)

2     260
3     140
6     125
16    290
17     90
19    140
21    220
24    125
25    200
26      0
27    240
37    170
38    170
43    150
45    190
46    220
47    170
50    320
55    210
57      0
59    290
63     70
64    230
Name: sodio, dtype: int64

That is what I need so far, but when I try to write a function like this (in order to get the confidence):

```
def valor_medio_intervalo(fabricante, variable, confianza):
   subconjunto = cereal_df.loc[cereal_df['fabricante'] == fabricante, cereal_df[variable]]
   inicio, final  = sm.stats.DescrStatsW(subconjunto[variable]).zconfint_mean(alpha = 1 - confianza) 
   return inicio, final
```

Then I run the function:

```
valor_medio_intervalo('Kelloggs', 'azúcar', 0.95)
```

And the output is:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-11420ac4d15f> in <module>()
      1 #TEST_CELL
----> 2 valor_medio_intervalo('Kelloggs', 'azúcar', 0.95)

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
   1296             if missing == len(indexer):
   1297                 axis_name = self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)
-> 1298                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   1299 
   1300             # We (temporarily) allow for some missing keys with .loc, except in

KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([ 6,  8,  5,  0,  8, 10, 14,  8,  6,  5, 12,  1,  9,  7, 13,  3,  2,\n            12, 13,  7,  0,  3, 10,  5, 13, 11,  7, 12, 12, 15,  9,  5,  3,  4,\n            11, 10, 11,  6,  9,  3,  6, 12,  3, 13,  6,  9,  7,  2, 10, 14,  3,\n             0,  0,  6, -1, 12,  8,  6,  2,  3,  0,  0,  0, 15,  3,  5,  3, 14,\n             3,  3, 12,  3,  3,  8],\n           dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"
```

I do not understand what is going on.
I appreciate your help or any hint.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just got the answer examining the code:

```
def valor_medio_intervalo(fabricante, variable, confianza):
 subconjunto = cereal_df.loc[cereal_df['fabricante'] == fabricante,cereal_df[variable]]
 inicio, final  = sm.stats.DescrStatsW(subconjunto[variable]).zconfint_mean(alpha = 1 - 
    confianza) 
 return inicio, final
```

in the line

```
inicio, final  = sm.stats.DescrStatsW(subconjunto[variable]).zconfint_mean(alpha = 1 - 
    confianza)
```

the

```
(subconjunto[variable])
```

is just

```
(subconjunto)
```